# Django - MultipleCheckBoxSelector with m2m field - How to add object instead of save_m2m()

Tags: django, django-forms

I use inlineformset_factory with a custom form option in order to change the queryset and the widget of a m2m field, ie: `ezMap`. I want the form to give the user the option to add or remove the current `selected_map` to the m2m field with CheckBoxSelectMultiple widget. However, I dont want to give the user the ability to remove other objects that were already there. The problem is when I save the formset with `formset.save_m2m()`, it overides the field and erase all objects that were already saved.

How could I just add a new object without erasing others?

[image]

---

models: (some of unecessary fields were removed)

```
class Shapefile(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class EzMap(models.Model):
    map_name = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    layers = models.ManyToManyField(Shapefile, verbose_name='Layers to display', null=True, blank=True)

class LayerStyle(models.Model):
    styleName = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    layer = models.ForeignKey(Shapefile)
    ezMap = models.ManyToManyField(EzMap)
```

forms:

```
class polygonLayerStyleFormset(forms.ModelForm):
    add_to_map = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.map_selected =  kwargs.pop("map_selected", None)
        super(polygonLayerStyleFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['conditionStyle'].help_text = "Put * if you want to select the entire table"
        self.fields['ezMap'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields['ezMap'].queryset = EzMap.objects.filter(id=self.map_selected.id)
        self.fields['ezMap'].help_text =""

    class Meta:
        model = LayerStyle

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(polygonLayerStyleFormset, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        instance.add_to_map = self.cleaned_data['add_to_map']
        return instance


ftlStylePolygonFormset = inlineformset_factory(Shapefile, LayerStyle, can_delete=True, extra=1, max_num=5,
                fields = ['styleName', 'conditionStyle', 'fillColor', 'fillOpacity', 'strokeColor', 'strokeWeight', 'ezMap'], form=polygonLayerStyleFormset)
```

views:

```
def setLayerStyle(request, map_name, layer_id):
    map_selected = EzMap.objects.get(map_name=map_name, created_by=request.user)
    layer_selected = Shapefile.objects.get(id=layer_id)
    layerStyle_selected = LayerStyle.objects.filter(layer=layer_selected)
    styleFormset = ftlStylePolygonFormset
    if request.POST:
        formset = styleFormset(request.POST, instance=layer_selected)
        if formset.is_valid():
            instances = formset.save()
            for instance in instances:
                if instance.add_to_map:
                    instance.ezMap.add(map_selecte)
                else:
                    instance.ezMap.remove(map_selected)
            save_link = u"/ezmapping/map/%s" % (map_name)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(save_link)
    else:
        formset = styleFormset(instance=layer_selected)
        #set initial data for add_to_map
        for form in formset:
            if form.instance.pk:
                if map_selected in form.instance.ezMap.all():
                    form.fields['add_to_map'].initial = {'add_to_map': True}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused as to what you're doing with the `ezMap` form field.  You set its queryset to a single-element list, then use a CheckboxSelectMultiple widget for it.  Are you setting up to let the user deselect that matching map, but not add new ones?

To do this at initialization, you need to define a custom base formset class and pass that in as the `formset` argument to your factory.

```
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet

class polygonLayerStyleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.map_selected =  kwargs.pop("map_selected", None)
        super(polygonLayerStyleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['conditionStyle'].help_text = "Put * if you want to select the entire table"
        self.fields['ezMap'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields['ezMap'].queryset = EzMap.objects.filter(id=self.map_selected.id)
        self.fields['ezMap'].help_text =""

    class Meta:
        model = LayerStyle

class polygonLayerStyleFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.map_selected =  kwargs.pop("map_selected", None)
        super(polygonLayerStyleFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _construct_form(self, i, **kwargs):
        kwargs['map_selected'] = self.map_selected
        return super(polygonLayerStyleFormset, self)._construct_form(i, **kwargs)

ftlStylePolygonFormset = inlineformset_factory(Shapefile, LayerStyle, formset=polygonLayerStyleFormset, form=polygonLaterStyleForm, # and other arguments as above
                                               )
```

It might be simpler to just go through the formset forms and directly change the field's queryset after creating it in your view:

```
    formset = ftlStylePolygonFormset(instance=layer_selected)
    for form in formset.forms:
        form.fields['ezMap'].queryset = EzMap.objects.filter(id=map_selected.id)
```

Speaking of which, the usual convention is to split the POST and GET cases in the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def setLayerStyle(request, map_name, layer_id):
    map_selected = EzMap.objects.get(map_name=map_name, created_by=request.user)
    layer_selected = Shapefile.objects.get(id=layer_id)
    layerStyle_selected = LayerStyle.objects.filter(layer=layer_selected)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ftlStylePolygonFormset(request.POST, instance=layer_selected, map_selected=map_selected)
        if formset.is_valid():
            instances = formset.save()
            save_link = u"/ezmapping/map/%s" % (map_name)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(save_link)
    else:
        formset = ftlStylePolygonFormset(instance=layer_selected, map_selected=map_selected)
    return render(request, "ezmapping/manage_layerStyle.html", {'layer_style': layerStyle_selected, 'layerStyleformset': formset, 'layer': layer_selected})
```

And it's better to use the `redirect` shortcut to reverse lookup a view for your redirect on success rather than hardcode the target URL.  And to use `get_object_or_404` or some equivalent when accessing objects based on URL arguments - right now a bogus URL will trigger an exception and give the user a 500 status error, which is undesirable.

To conditionally add to the `ezMap` relationship:

```
class polygonLayerStyleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    add_to_map = forms.BooleanField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(polygonLayerStyleForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        instance.add_to_map = self.cleaned_data['add_to-map']
        return instance
```

Then in the view:

```
instances = formset.save()
for instance in instances:
    if instance.add_to_map:
        instance.ezMap.add(map_selected)
```

You could also do the `add` call in the save method, but then you'd have to set the map as member data sometime previously - and more importantly, deal with the `commit=False` case.

Comment: thank you very much, you were right, the ezmap form field is there to allow the user to only add or remove the currend selected_map to the m2m field

Comment: all your explanation is perfect, except for the `get_object_or_404` that I am not sure to understand. Do you mean I should use `get_object_or_404` instead of `layer_selected = Shapefile.objects.get(id=layer_id)` and others?

Comment: That's how I would do it.  Basically, think about what you would like to happen if a user edits the url to include a bad map name.  Or, more innocently, bookmarks a url for a map that is later renamed - in that latter case it would be courteous to set up a permanent redirect,  but even a 404 is better than a 500.

Comment: Your solution is working(I used the simpler one) but when I save the formset with formset.save_m2m() it overides the m2m field instead of just adding a new object to it. Do you have an idea how I could do? (see updated question)

Comment: That's normal behavior - the form widget represents the entire m2m relationship, not just a possible connection to the current map.  What you're attempting gets a little complicated.  I would not include the `ezMap` field in the form at all.  Instead, I would use a boolean field declared just on the form, and handle the `add` call on the m2m relationship in either the view code or in the form's `save` method.  The exact details are too complicated for a comment, I'll add to the answer.

Comment: Thank you again. I have managed to set the initial value of add_to_map field True/False if the ezMap is in the m2m field or not. However, when I want to uncheck the add_to_map and remove the m2m without modifying other fields, the save method is not launched just like if the form was not modified. Do you know why? (see edited question)

Comment: Forms use `self.initial` to determine whether or not a field changed, and formsets don't save instances for forms that didn't change.  How exactly are you setting the initial values?

Comment: you can see it in the question views.py (I have put a comment). If add_to_map is checked the formset save, but it does not save when add_to_map is unchecked.

Comment: Make sure you do that in the POST path as well.  The forms don't directly persist between the two requests, and it's the POST case that actually compares the submitted values to `self.initial`.